# Foreign Key column issue

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to connect two tables using a foreign key.

**Table 1: (Plaque)**:

```
PLAQUE_ID   PLAQUE_TYPE      facility_id    FACILITY    PLAQUE_SUB_LOCATION
2468        Lettering         26          Gorab Building    DONOR WALL FRIEND LEVEL
2469        Lettering         36          abc Hospital  MUSIC & ENTERTAINMENT WALL
2476        Facility Plaque   46          abc Hospital  1ST FL OFFICE ROOM
```

Table 2: **Facility**

```
FACILITY_ID FACILITY             FACILITY_DESC  PLAQUE_ID
26          Gorab Building                         2468
36          abc Hospital                           2469
46          abc Hospital                           2476
```

I don't want the facility table to have same rows as Plaque table. I want distinct names in facility column. I thought the only way to do that is make `FACILITY` column as foreign key to `Plaque` table but I am confused because about that can we make such a column a foreign key. I have seen only `ID` columns as foreign keys. The reason behind distinct values in `FACILITY` column is because every row will have a large description about that `FACILITY` in the `FACILITY_DESC` column.

An answer would be very appreciated.

Comment: So why not just query the `DISTINCT` facilities?

Comment: A foreign key can only ever reference the **primary key** of the target table (most likely `Plaque_ID`), or any column(s) that are part of a **unique index**. Since `Facility` in `Plaque` isn't unique, you cannot put a unique index on it - so you won't be able to reference it using a foreign key

Comment: What is the relationship between Plaques and Facilities? I would guess that a facility can have any number of plaques, but every plaque must exist in one and only one facilty. Is this correct?

Comment: @FreshPrinceofSO at this point I am trying to build up the relational database, So I need to figure out to normalize the facility table so that if there are like 80,000 Records in Plaque table then there only 200 facilities in facility table(distinct count) and then the description can be typed in those 200 not 80,000

Comment: @RBarry Young yes that is correct

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the PLAUQUE_ID in the Facility table because you have a facility_id in the Plaque table and that is enough to make the connection between the Plague and the Facitlity tables. Just use a simple join. For example:

```
SELECT Plaque_ID, Plaque_Type, Facility FROM Plaque INNER JOIN Facility ON Plaque.Facility_ID = Facility.Facility_ID
```

I thik you should set the Facility column of the Facility table to be unique and also remove the Facility column of the Plaque table. Remember the Plaque table should describe the plaque properties onlu.
Also consider adding a new PlaqueType table and replacing the Plaque Type column of the Plaque id with its coresponding foreign key ot the PlaqueType table.

Here is a simple explanation of how to join tables http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: I followed you instructions but that is giving me distinct rows of facility and corresponding Plaque_id, Plaque_type. But I also want the other plaques that have same facility associated with them to be displayed. How will I get those plaques which have same facility.

Comment: the plaque table has 80,000 Rows. A plaque has only one facility but a facility has many plaques. So how to have distinct rows in Facility table with foreign key connection in plaque table.

Comment: I found a solution to this, that just produce the facility ids in plaque table using Vlookup in Excel . Facilities with same name will have same facility id